# How to redirect to another page using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ajax call to perform functionality in a service file and if the response is successful, I want to redirect the page to another url. Currently, I am doing this by plain JS code `window.location = response['message'];`. But I need to replace it with AngularJS code. I have looked various solutions on stackoverflow, they used `$location`. But I am new to AngularJS and having trouble to implement it.

```
$http({
            url: RootURL+'app-code/common.service.php',
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            dataType: 'json',
            data:data + '&method=signin'

        }).success(function (response) {

            console.log(response);

            if (response['code'] == '420') {

                $scope.message = response['message'];
                $scope.loginPassword = '';
            }
            else if (response['code'] != '200'){

                $scope.message = response['message'];
                $scope.loginPassword = '';
            }
            else {
                window.location = response['message'];
            }
            //  $scope.users = data.users;    // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here
        })
```

Comment: Why do you need to use angular for that? Any specific reason? document.location is the proper way and probably more efficient than the angular way

Answer (score 236, accepted):

You can use Angular `$window`:

```
$window.location.href = '/index.html';
```

Example usage in a contoller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('LoginCtrl', LoginCtrl);

    LoginCtrl.$inject = ['$window', 'loginSrv', 'notify'];

    function LoginCtrl($window, loginSrv, notify) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.validateUser = function () {
             loginSrv.validateLogin(vm.username, vm.password).then(function (data) {          
                if (data.isValidUser) {    
                    $window.location.href = '/index.html';
                }
                else
                    alert('Login incorrect');
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: I have used $window.location.href but it gives an error of undefined function $window.location. Do I need to include any dependency for this?

Comment: No, but you may need to inject $window into your controller. See my edited answer.

Comment: Its window.location.href not $window.location.href

Comment: @user3623224 - it's not, actually ;)

Comment: @Junaid window.location.href is for the traditional window object, $window.location.href is for the AngularJS $window object, here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Answer (score 123):

You can redirect to a new URL in different ways.

1. You can use [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) which will also refresh the page
2. You can "stay inside" the single page app and use [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) in which case you can choose between `$location.path(YOUR_URL);` or `$location.url(YOUR_URL);`. So the basic difference between the 2 methods is that `$location.url()` also affects get parameters whilst `$location.path()` does not.

I would recommend reading the docs on `$location` and `$window` so you get a better grasp on the differences between them.

Answer (score 16):

`$location.path('/configuration/streaming');` 
this will work...
inject the location service in controller

Answer (score 13):

I used the below code to redirect to new page

```
$window.location.href = '/foldername/page.html';
```

and injected $window object in my controller function.

Answer (score 12):

It might help you!!

The AngularJs code-sample

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // For any unmatched url, send to /index
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "login.html",
      controller: "LoginCheckController"
    })
    .state('SuccessPage', {
      url: "/SuccessPage",
      templateUrl: "SuccessPage.html",
      //controller: "LoginCheckController"
    });
});

app.controller('LoginCheckController', ['$scope', '$location', LoginCheckController]);

function LoginCheckController($scope, $location) {

  $scope.users = [{
    UserName: 'chandra',
    Password: 'hello'
  }, {
    UserName: 'Harish',
    Password: 'hi'
  }, {
    UserName: 'Chinthu',
    Password: 'hi'
  }];

  $scope.LoginCheck = function() {
    $location.path("SuccessPage");
  };

  $scope.go = function(path) {
    $location.path("/SuccessPage");
  };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced issues in redirecting to a different page in an angular app as well

You can add the `$window` as Ewald has suggested in his answer, or if you don't want to add the `$window`, just add an timeout and it will work!

```
setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "http://whereeveryouwant.com";
    }, 500);
```

Answer (score 5):

In AngularJS you can **redirect your form** (on submit) to other page by using `window.location.href='';` like below:

```
postData(email){
    if (email=='undefined') {
      this.Utils.showToast('Invalid Email');
    } else {
      var origin = 'Dubai';
      this.download.postEmail(email, origin).then(data => { 
           ...
      });
      window.location.href = "https://www.thesoftdesign.com/";      
    }
  }
```

Simply try this:

```
window.location.href = "https://www.thesoftdesign.com/";
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way I use is

```
app.controller("Back2Square1Controller", function($scope, $location) {
    window.location.assign(basePath + "/index.html");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this is using $state.go('statename', {params...}) is faster and more friendly for user experience in cases when you don't have to reload and bootsraping whole app config and stuff

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.appcode')
        .controller('YourController', YourController);

    YourController.$inject = ['rootURL', '$scope', '$state', '$http'];

    function YourController(rootURL, $scope, $state, $http) {

        $http({
                url: rootURL + 'app-code/common.service.php',
                method: "POST",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                dataType: 'json',
                data:data + '&method=signin'

            }).success(function (response) {
                if (response['code'] == '420') {

                    $scope.message = response['message'];
                    $scope.loginPassword = '';
                } else if (response['code'] != '200') {

                    $scope.message = response['message'];
                    $scope.loginPassword = '';
                } else {
                    // $state.go('home'); // select here the route that you want to redirect
                    $state.go(response['state']); // response['state'] should be a route on your app.routes
                }
            })
    }

});
```

// routes

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(routes);

    routes.$inject = [
        '$stateProvider',
        '$urlRouterProvider'
    ];

    function routes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        /**
         * Default path for any unmatched url
        */
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/app/home/home.html',
                controller: 'Home'
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: '/app/login/login.html',
                controller: 'YourController'
            })
            // ... more routes .state
   }

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using 
`location.href="./index.html"`

or create 
`scope $window`

and using 
`$window.location.href="./index.html"`

Answer (score 0):

```
 (function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("myApp")
       .controller("LoginCtrl", LoginCtrl);

function LoginCtrl($scope, $log, loginSrv, notify) {

    $scope.validateUser = function () {
        loginSrv.validateLogin($scope.username, $scope.password)
            .then(function (data) {
                if (data.isValidUser) {
                    window.location.href = '/index.html';
                }
                else {
                    $log.error("error handler message");
                }
            })
    }
} }());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a link then: in the html have:

```
<button type="button" id="btnOpenLine" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="orderMaster.openLineItems()">Order Line Items</button>
```

in the typescript file

```
public openLineItems() {
if (this.$stateParams.id == 0) {
    this.Flash.create('warning', "Need to save order!", 3000);
    return
}
this.$window.open('#/orderLineitems/' + this.$stateParams.id);
```

}

I hope you see this example helpful as it was for me along with the other answers.