# hard refresh of browser page and then redirect to a url using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, reload

I am trying to reload the page and redirect it to another one, 
or just redirect it to another one but I can't do that by

```
window.location.href
```

or

```
windown.location
```

as I have an Angular Single Page app which catches the route and instead of reloading the page opens the partials directly

I did try -

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

but it reloads the page and cannot change the url
I have also tried -

```
window.location.assign
```

and

```
window.location.replace
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you could try `window.open('url', '_self')`

Comment: are you able to replicate this in a fiddle or plunk? http://plnkr.co/edit/5B6hH1Ro7CS4PmTDXTy4?p=preview ...you have to view it in a popped out window though...

Comment: I just achieved it by hit and trial. what I did was after changing the location by $window.location.href = url; which did not work for me previously and now also when used alone. I added the window.location.reload(true) in the next line so that the window is reloaded with the new url instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three cases where AngularJS will perform a full page reload:

Links that contain target element

Example:

```
<a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self"> link  </a>
```

Absolute links that go to a different domain
Example:

```
<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>
```

Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base is defined
Example:

```
<a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>
```

**Updated:**

Using javascript:

The $location service allows you to change only the URL; it does not allow you to reload the page. When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, please use a lower level API: $window.location.href.

See:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: this three ways are not angularjs specific, this is what about any html page :p

Answer (score 2):

For redirect to different page you should use

```
$window.open('url', '_self')
```

Which will load your page again.

Comment: It is not working, I have also tried var win = window.self win.open(url,"_self")

Comment: I am calling this in a child scope does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @deadman are you using modal window? why you don't think about bootstrap popup https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

try 
    `window.location = url;`

do remember that the url must have a protocol i.e http:// or https://

Comment: as I said in the question the window.location does not work and yes I did add http://

Comment: you can also try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941876/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

So you need to change the hash on the end of the URL? i.e. from `#/` to `#/otherpage/` ?

If so, `location.hash = "/otherpage/";`

Comment: No, any url changes they are captured by angular and it does not let the entire page refresh, just changes the view and controller. thats why window.location.reload(true) works for me and no other solution among the ones that I showed above but I want to change the url to in addition to the url change

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location, if AngularJS  is using HTML5 mode, it never performs a full page reload in a modern browser.

> ## HTML5 mode
>
> In HTML5 mode, the $location service getters and setters interact with the browser URL address through the HTML5 history API. This allows for use of regular URL path and search segments, instead of their hashbang equivalents. If the HTML5 History API is not supported by a browser, the $location service will fall back to using the hashbang URLs automatically. This frees you from having to worry about whether the browser displaying your app supports the history API or not; the $location service transparently uses the best available option.
>
> Opening a regular URL in a legacy browser -> redirects to a hashbang URL
> Opening hashbang URL in a modern browser -> rewrites to a regular URL
> Note that in this mode, Angular intercepts all links (subject to the "Html link rewriting" rules below) and updates the url in a way that **never performs a full page reload**.

(Emphasis mine)

Since Hashbang mode is the default, the code must be setting HTML5 mode somewhere.