# How to recognise urls starting with anchor(#) in urls.py file in django?

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I have starting building my application in angularJS and django, and after creating a login page, I am trying to redirect my application to a new url after successful login. I am using `$location` variable to redirect my page. Here is my code:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        },
        url: '/pos/login_authentication/'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        user = response.data
        console.log(response.data)
        if (user.is_active) {
            $location.url("dashboard")
        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('errorCallback')
    });
}
```

My initial url was `http://localhost:8000/pos/`, and after hitting the log in button, the above function calls, and I am redirected to `http://localhost:8000/pos/#/dashboard`. But I am unable to catch this url in my regex pattern in `urls.py` file:

My project `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^pos/', include('pos.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And my `pos` application's `urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^login_authentication/$', views.login_authentication, name='login_authentication'),
    url(r'^#/dashboard/$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard')
]
```

Using this, I am getting the same login page on visiting this `http://localhost:8000/pos/#/dashboard` link. This means that in my `urls.py` file of my `pos` application, it is mapping my `http://localhost:8000/pos/#/dashboard` to first object of `urlpatterns`:`url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')`. How do I make python differentiate between both the links?

Comment: That sort of page access is pretty typical of Angular. You'll want to look at how to have Angular request a specific URL from the Django side when that URL is requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27941966/5159284), I figured a good redirection method through angular which doesn't append any anchor tag using $window:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password
      },
      url: '/pos/login_authentication/'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        user = response.data
        console.log(response.data)
        if (user.is_active) {
            $window.location.href = '/pos/dashboard';
        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('errorCallback')
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some major misunderstanding about and anchor in url. The anchor is called officially [`Fragment identifier`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), it's not part of the main url, so if you have `#` when you visit an url like `http://localhost:8000/pos/#/dashboard`, your browser would treat the remaining `#/dashboard` as the anchor in page that `http://localhost:8000/pos/` renders. You shouldn't be even using it in your `urls.py` definition. Please read the link above more carefully about the usage of an anchor.

Comment: I got it. What approach and changes should i make in my login function so that I can redirect my page to a link such as `http://localhost:8000/pos/dashboard`?

Comment: Check this SO answer on how to do the redirection after authentication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870619/django-after-login-redirect-user-to-his-custom-page-mysite-com-username#answer-7061358. Note that I'm using an anchor for this link :)

Comment: Noticed it! Thanks! :)

Comment: Although the post that you mentioned was helpful, but the method that they mentioned was returning new url in `response.data` in the successCallBack but not redirecting to a new url.

Comment: Are you sure we are looking at the same thing? I don't even know what are you talking about, like `response.data` and `successCallBack`, where are they defined?