# angular $location path change

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm trying to change the view using $location.

This is how i tried to do this.

**View**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">

        <button ng-click="click();">Press</button>

</body>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope,$location){


   $scope.click = function(){

      $location.path('/main');

   }; 

});
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'myApp.view2',
    'myApp.version'
]).
        config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider, testCtrl) {
                $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

                $routeProvider


                        .when('/main',
                                {
                                    templateUrl: '/view2.html',
                                    controller: testCtrl

                                })

                        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
            }]);
```

So when i click the button i can see the url changes from

```
http://localhost:8383/etest/index.html
```

to

```
http://localhost:8383/etest/index.html#/main
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Does the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941876/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-angular-js help you?

Comment: There is nothing to fix. This is the expected behavior. But you're using ng-route without any ng-view in your index.html page. So the main view can't display itself anywhere. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: try to put this  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!'); ..as JB says it's not a bug ... but if you want to see url different you can use html5 mode .. activate it with  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: @JBNizet where should i include ng-view ?

Answer (score 0):

You missed out to include ng-view.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-view></div>
</body>

 // view2.html
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <button ng-click="click();">Press</button>
</div>

 app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider, testCtrl) {
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
            $routeProvider
                    .when('/main', {
                                templateUrl: 'templates/view2.html',
                                controller: testCtrl
                            })
                    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
        }]);

  $scope.click = function(){

  $location.path('/contact'); //you are in main path, So give different path then only you can see the location change easily.
 $route.reload(); // reload the route
```

};