# How to change url using angular or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a function that change to another page depending certain value, I just can't find a way to do it.

Something like this

get the current page www.mypage.com

insert a new route

url = "/reports"

so when the funcion executes the page will redirect to www.mypage.com/reports or anything depending the url

```
$scope.searchPage = function (url) {

/// page = www.mypage.com + url


        };
```

Comment: Try `$scope.searchPage = function (url) { return www.mypage.com + url};`

Comment: no page is not supposed to be hardcoded i want to get it with a js funcion I heard there is something like $location

Comment: [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location), [How to redirect to another page using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941876/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-angular-js), [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: use $location.path(url) and see this too window.location.hostname

Comment: Use `$location.path(url)` or `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$location`([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)) to do this and your code will look like:

```
$location.path('/reports');
```

this will navigate to `yourdomain.com/reports`.

Another solution would be to use `$window`([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)) like:

```
$window.location.href = 'http://www.mypage.com/reports'
```

I personally use `$location` service to navigate inside the angularjs application and if you want to redirect to an external page in new tab via javascript you can do something like:

```
window.open('http://www.mypage.com/reports', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the URL of a page with JavaScript, you just specify it on `document.location.href`:

```
document.location.href = 'http://example.com/new-page';
```

It is just a string, so you can build it however you want and pass it in.

For Angular, you can use the `$window.location.href` instead. Just be sure to inject the `$window` dependency:

```
$window.location.href = 'http://example.com/new-page';
```

Using the Angular way will allow a single-page-app to remain single page if it's within your site.