# How to use $routeProvider by javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, route-provider

Is there any possibility to call "dashboard.html" without using `<a href="#!dashboard">Some text</a>`? I wont to call "dashboard.html" from javascript.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'loginRegister.html',
    controller : 'loginRegister'
  })
.when('/dashboard', {
    templateUrl : 'dashboard.html',
    controller : 'dashboard'
  })
})

app.controller('loginRegister', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.showDashboard = function() {
         // CALL dashboard.html FROM HERE
    }
})
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: consider using ui-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the location function https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

OR you can use the $window inside AngularJS controller

```
$window.location.href = '/index.html';
```

It think you will have a complete response here [How to redirect to another page using Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941876/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

this is the code for redirecting in angular js app

```
$location.path('/dashboard');
```