# How to redirect Page using Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to know how to redirect to another page using Angular Js.

I already follow several questions here and don't find any answer with works successfully

This is my code :

```
var app = angular.module('formExample',[]);
app.controller('formCtrl',function($scope,$http){    
    $scope.insertData=function(){      

      //  if($scope.name =='' && $scope.email == '' && $scope.message = '' && $scope.price =='' && $scope.date == null && $scope.client == ''){return;}
        $http.post("/php/login.php", {
           "email": $scope.email, "password": $scope.password
        }).then(function(response, $location){
                alert("Login Successfully");
                $scope.email = '';
                $scope.password = '';
                $location.path('/clients');

            },function(error){
                alert("Sorry! Data Couldn't be inserted!");
                console.error(error);

            });
        }
    });
```

I´m getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

Comment: You need inject `$location` in your controller.

Comment: Detailed answer is already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941876/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-angular-js) in stackoverflow

Comment: Inject $location in your controller and don't forget to remove it from the success callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plain JS

```
window.location.href = '/my-other-page'
```

Or, if you are using 'ui-router'

```
$state.reload()
```

or

```
$state.go($state.current.name, {}, {reload: true})
```

don't forget to inject $state into your controller dependencies:

```
app.controller('formCtrl',function($scope, $http, $state){
```

Comment: @Maxwelt Unknown provider: $urlProvider <- $url

Comment: inject '$state' into your controller's dependencies

Comment: app.controller('formCtrl',function($scope,$http, $state){

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject **`$location`** to your controller,

```
app.controller('formCtrl',function($scope,$http,$location){
```

Comment: Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $urlProvider <- $url

Comment: i do not see anywhere urlProvider

Comment: Well dont work, because path is not defined @Sajeetharan

Comment: What ? I don't get it

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect using $window in your controller.

```
$window.location.href = '/index.html';
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $urlProvider <- $url

Comment: `$window.location.href` should be used only for full page reload.