# angularjs: how to redirect to a different url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs app I want to redirect to a different site / domain. I am using:

```
$location.url(someOtherDomain);
```

How can I redirect to this url from my angularjs app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another page using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941876/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$window` object that can be injected:

`return $window.location = 'https://someurl.com'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method:

```
$window.open('https://someurl.com','_blank');
```