# How to redirect in JavaScript that is in angular 5 application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a script that is loaded with JavaScript code in an angular application:

```
function reloadgame(gameId, user) {
  window.location  =  window.location.href.replace(/demo/ig, 'Real');
  return false;    
}
```

The script doesnt work, and my suspicion is because of the way angular works.
The conventional known ways failed to work too such as the ways described [here](https://appendto.com/2016/04/javascript-redirect-how-to-redirect-a-web-page-with-javascript/).

I tried to reload the page with this function:

```
location.reload();
```

and it worked.

However, I don't want to refresh the page. I want to redirect the user to a new path.

How can it be achieved given that I use JavaScript in an angular 5 app?

Comment: Angularjs or Angular 2+??

Comment: Angularjs.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which  angular version you are expecting.

> In Angular 2 and above

try this

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class className{
 constructor(private router: Router) {
  }
  redirectToPage()
  {
   this.router.navigate(['yourpath']);// it will be redirect to your path 
  }
}
```

> In angularjs

see this

[How to redirect to another page using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941876/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-angularjs)

Comment: That is interesting. But my javascript code isnt inside a typescript file, but in an external javascript file.